# Microsoft Academic API searching by Title

Tags: json, api, web-services, search, academic-graph

I am trying to use the [Microsoft Academic Search API](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/565d753be597ed16ac3ffc03) to find articles by title.  As it is, I have a series of test titles, for instance, "Emotion detection for wheelchair navigation enhancement," an article [I know appears precisely once](https://academic.microsoft.com/#/search?iq=%2540Emotion%2520detection%2520for%2520wheelchair%2520navigation%2520enhancement%2540&q=Emotion%20detection%20for%20wheelchair%20navigation%20enhancement&filters=&from=0&sort=0), it does not appear in the API results.

Here is the URL call:

```
https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Ti='Emotion detection for wheelchair navigation enhancement'&model=latest&count=1&offset=0&attributes=Ti,Y,AA.AfN,C.CN,J.JN,E
```

Here is the associated HTTP request:

```
GET https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Ti='Emotion detection for wheelchair navigation enhancement'&model=latest&count=1&offset=0&attributes=Ti,Y,AA.AfN,C.CN,J.JN,E HTTP/1.1
Host: api.projectoxford.ai
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
```

And these are the results I get:

```
apim-request-id: 1e0501f9-6398-4bd1-8a3d-36bff155bdd2
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Date: Fri, 18 Nov 2016 16:58:15 GMT
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 90
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "expr": "Ti='Emotion detection for wheelchair navigation enhancement'",
  "entities": []
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With Ti parameter you should put all your text in **lowercase** and **delete all special characters**.

You should use **E.DN parameter** (an Extended Metadata Attributes) which is "Display Name of the paper" to have the full name of the paper (with uppercase and special characters).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/paperentityattributes#extended-metadata-attributes

Answer (score 0):

try adding three dots at the end of 'Ti' that is,

```
Ti='Emotion detection for wheelchair navigation enhancement'...
```

More information about formatting can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/queryexpressionsyntax

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your search and making the query string **lowercase** did the trick for me, so this works:

```
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Ti='emotion detection for wheelchair navigation enhancement'&model=latest&count=10&offset=0&attributes=Id
```

I couldn't find any references in the docs that explain this behaviour, please feel free to comment in case you do.